# Switching Activity to firebase- app shuts down

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase

I have a problem switching activity when a user would click on a link from  MainActivity, the app will just shut down, i am not sure if i have a problem with the project structure or declaring the class correctly and the extends.

Basically what i did is try to implement Firebase example project provided on the website into one activity i have in my app, in order to have a way to let members log in, i striped down the initial code provided [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/samples/logindemo/MainActivity.java) and implemented it in my second activity window, the code in the link is for the MainActivity and i wanted it to be as LoginFragment ( only a name ) didnt use fragments.

thus after minimizing the code ( deleting google, facebook, etc ) options i ended up with this :

```
package net.we4x4.we4x4;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.AuthData;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

 public class LoginFragment extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /* *************************************
     *              GENERAL                *
     ***************************************/
/* TextView that is used to display information about the logged in user */
    private TextView mLoggedInStatusTextView;

    /* A dialog that is presented until the Firebase authentication finished. */
    private ProgressDialog mAuthProgressDialog;

    /* A reference to the Firebase */
    private Firebase mFirebaseRef;

    /* Data from the authenticated user */
    private AuthData mAuthData;

    /* Listener for Firebase session changes */
    private Firebase.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    /* *************************************
     *              PASSWORD               *
     ***************************************/
    private Button mPasswordLoginButton;

    /* *************************************
     *            ANONYMOUSLY              *
     ***************************************/
    private Button mAnonymousLoginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* Load the view and display it */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* *************************************
     *               PASSWORD              *
     ***************************************/
        mPasswordLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_with_password);
        mPasswordLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginWithPassword();
            }
        });

    /* *************************************
     *              ANONYMOUSLY            *
     ***************************************/
    /* Load and setup the anonymous login button */
        mAnonymousLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_anonymously);
        mAnonymousLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginAnonymously();
            }
        });

    /* *************************************
     *               GENERAL               *
     ***************************************/
        mLoggedInStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status);

    /* Create the Firebase ref that is used for all authentication with Firebase */
        mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_url));

    /* Setup the progress dialog that is displayed later when authenticating with Firebase */
        mAuthProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAuthProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        mAuthProgressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating with Firebase...");
        mAuthProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mAuthProgressDialog.show();

        mAuthStateListener = new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
                mAuthProgressDialog.hide();
                setAuthenticatedUser(authData);
            }
        };
    /* Check if the user is authenticated with Firebase already. If this is the case we can set the authenticated
     * user and hide hide any login buttons */
        mFirebaseRef.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        // if changing configurations, stop tracking firebase session.
        mFirebaseRef.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    /**
     * This method fires when any startActivityForResult finishes. The requestCode maps to
     * the value passed into startActivityForResult.
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /* If a user is currently authenticated, display a logout menu */
        if (this.mAuthData != null) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            logout();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Unauthenticate from Firebase and from providers where necessary.
     */
    private void logout() {
        if (this.mAuthData != null) {
        /* logout of Firebase */
            mFirebaseRef.unauth();
            }
        /* Update authenticated user and show login buttons */
            setAuthenticatedUser(null);
        }


    /**
     * This method will attempt to authenticate a user to firebase given an oauth_token (and other
     * necessary parameters depending on the provider)
     */
    private void authWithFirebase(final String provider, Map<String, String> options) {
        if (options.containsKey("error")) {
            showErrorDialog(options.get("error"));
        } else {
            mAuthProgressDialog.show();
            if (provider.equals("twitter")) {
                // if the provider is twitter, we pust pass in additional options, so use the options endpoint
                mFirebaseRef.authWithOAuthToken(provider, options, new AuthResultHandler(provider));
            } else {
                // if the provider is not twitter, we just need to pass in the oauth_token
                mFirebaseRef.authWithOAuthToken(provider, options.get("oauth_token"), new AuthResultHandler(provider));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Once a user is logged in, take the mAuthData provided from Firebase and "use" it.
     */
    private void setAuthenticatedUser(AuthData authData) {
        if (authData != null) {
        /* Hide all the login buttons */
            mPasswordLoginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAnonymousLoginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mLoggedInStatusTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        /* show a provider specific status text */
            String name = null;
            if (authData.getProvider().equals("facebook")
                    || authData.getProvider().equals("google")
                    || authData.getProvider().equals("twitter")) {
                name = (String) authData.getProviderData().get("displayName");
            } else if (authData.getProvider().equals("anonymous")
                    || authData.getProvider().equals("password")) {
                name = authData.getUid();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid provider: " + authData.getProvider());
            }
            if (name != null) {
                mLoggedInStatusTextView.setText("Logged in as " + name + " (" + authData.getProvider() + ")");
            }
        } else {
        /* No authenticated user show all the login buttons */
            mPasswordLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mAnonymousLoginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mLoggedInStatusTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        this.mAuthData = authData;
    /* invalidate options menu to hide/show the logout button */
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }



    /**
     * Show errors to users
     */
    private void showErrorDialog(String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Error")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }

    /**
     * Utility class for authentication results
     */
    private class AuthResultHandler implements Firebase.AuthResultHandler {

        private final String provider;

        public AuthResultHandler(String provider) {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
            mAuthProgressDialog.hide();
            Log.i(TAG, provider + " auth successful");
            setAuthenticatedUser(authData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            mAuthProgressDialog.hide();
            showErrorDialog(firebaseError.toString());
        }
    }

    /* ************************************
     *              PASSWORD              *
     **************************************
     */
    public void loginWithPassword() {
        mAuthProgressDialog.show();
        mFirebaseRef.authWithPassword("test@firebaseuser.com", "test1234", new AuthResultHandler("password"));
    }

    /* ************************************
     *             ANONYMOUSLY            *
     **************************************
     */
    private void loginAnonymously() {
        mAuthProgressDialog.show();
        mFirebaseRef.authAnonymously(new AuthResultHandler("anonymous"));
    }



public void switchToRegister(View v) {
    Intent Register = new Intent(this, Register.class);
    startActivity(Register);
}

}
```

and as you would guys see i declared the class as public and extended AppCompatActivity ( not sure what i had to extend just learned that from another tutorial ) i also tried to extend it from Application, which i thought could work, but then all sort of errors poped up in the code listed :

in the manifesto :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.we4x4.we4x4.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginFragment">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Register">
    </activity>

    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

in line 27  under .LoginFragment it says that it is not assignable to android.app.activity ?

and then in the code itself LoginFragment :

i get these errors which i could not solve :
line 58 - setContentView cant resolve this method ?
      setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

line 63 findViewById also cant resolve this method ?

```
         mPasswordLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_with_password);
```

the same anonymous option line 75
       mAnonymousLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_anonymously);

the same problem with line 86 findViewById ?
             mLoggedInStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status);

Apparently i need to create findViewById mehtod if i want to extends Application, but i did not proceed with this since i do not know if i should extends from Application, considering i do not get any of these errors in the code when i extends from MainActivity or AppCompatActivity

also i get on line 114 cant resolve this method
              super.onDestroy();

and few others .... ?

so i am not sure how to solve this problem ? should i extends Application and tackle these errors ( and how to solve these errrors ) or keep the extend of MainActivity or AppCompatActivity ? which contain no error in the code but will not function properly switching activity:

my MainActivity is :

```
 package net.we4x4.we4x4;

import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.MediaController;
 import android.widget.VideoView;

 import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String VID_URL = "http://res.cloudinary.com/wi4x4/video/upload/v1457270321/bolivia_njb6r0.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);


    VideoView vid = (VideoView)findViewById(R. id.VidClip);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(VID_URL);
    vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vid.setVideoURI(video);
    vid.requestFocus();


}
 }


public void switchToLoginFragment(View v) {
    Intent LoginFragment = new Intent(this, LoginFragment.class);
    startActivity(LoginFragment);
}
public void switchToRegister(View v) {
    Intent Register = new Intent(this, Register.class);
    startActivity(Register);
}
```

}

and the error log is :

```
 6:16:51 PM AssertionError: Wrong element range PsiJavaFile:LoginFragment.java; committed=true
```

android monitor :

```
 03-07 18:19:52.512 21730-21730/net.we4x4.we4x4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: net.we4x4.we4x4, PID: 21730
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.we4x4.we4x4/net.we4x4.we4x4.LoginFragment}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For a custom firebase host you must first set your authentication server before using authentication features!
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For a custom firebase host you must first set your authentication server before using authentication features!
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.authentication.AuthenticationManager.checkServerSettings(AuthenticationManager.java:221)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.authentication.AuthenticationManager.addAuthStateListener(AuthenticationManager.java:625)
                                                                 at com.firebase.client.Firebase.addAuthStateListener(Firebase.java:555)
                                                                 at net.we4x4.we4x4.LoginFragment.onCreate(LoginFragment.java:107)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow makes a lousy debugger. There is **way** too much information in this question to answer it. I've answered one problem below, but for the rest: set up a [**minimal*, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces a single problem. That requires that you take the effort to isolate the problem, possibly outside of your app. Why that is useful and necessary are all described in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree with you, and yes i need to work on my debugging skills in order to locate the problem more precisely. Well as i am learning to code and dev. these also skills that must be acquired, appreciate your advice anyhow, You could've add a  suggestion on what might have been the issue at least.

Comment: I added an answer before commenting. But the whole point of my comment was that few people are likely to spend time going through heaps of code to isolate the problem for you. Learning to debug is great, learning to isolate your problem is crucial too if you're going to post problems on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.we4x4.we4x4/net.we4x4.we4x4.LoginFragment}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For a custom firebase host you must first set your authentication server before using authentication features!

Comes from this line:

mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_url));

The reason is that `firebase_url` is not in the form `https://yours.firebaseio.com`.