# FireBase Authentication Server Hosting Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to authenticate users on my android app, using firebase. I have already initiated and deployed the server, using the firebase CLI. When I go to the firebase url, it says that I have "successfully setup Firebase Hosting". But my app keeps crashing with this error message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: For a custom firebase host you must first set your authentication server before using authentication features!

I have gone through this question too: [Switching Activity to firebase- app shuts down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846122/switching-activity-to-firebase-app-shuts-down)
But the problem for me is not the incorrect url.